# Como pegar um valor no link javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá! Como posso pegar determinados valores em um link? Tenho uma url assim:
slide.html?titulo=Nome&volume=12 porém só quero exibir o valor do volume em um h2.

Meu Código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var html = '';

  var query = location.search.slice(1);
  var partesDaQuery = query.split("&");
  var json = {};

    partesDaQuery.forEach(function(partes){
      var chaveValor = partes.split('=');
      var paramsKey = chaveValor[0];
      var paramsValue = chaveValor[1];
      json[paramsKey] = paramsValue;

      html += '<h2></h2>';
      console.log(paramsValue);
        });
    $("#lista").html(html);

  });
```

Comment: O link é sempre neste padrão?

Comment: É sim. Vai manter desse jeito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de pegar a string, uma delas é usando `split('=').pop()` se a string que quer capturar da URL for sempre a última depois do `=`:

**URL da página:** `slide.html?titulo=Nome&volume=12`

```
var string = location.href.split("=").pop();
```

O resultado de `string` é `12`.

Um exemplo como se `local` fosse a URL da página:

```js
local = "slide.html?titulo=Nome&volume=12"; // apenas para exemplo

var string = local.split("=").pop();

alert(string);
```

**Outra forma com `lastIndexOf`:**

```
var url_ = location.href;
var string = url_.substring(url_.lastIndexOf("=")+1,url_.length);
```

Exemplo:

```js
local = "slide.html?titulo=Nome&volume=12";

var string = local.substring(local.lastIndexOf("=")+1,local.length);

alert(string);
```

**Pegar qualquer parâmetro:**

```
var url_ = new URL(location.href);
var string = url_.searchParams.get("volume");
```

Caso queira pegar outro parâmetro, basta trocar `volume` em `url_.searchParams.get("volume");`

Comment: Funcionou. Vlw. E caso eu queira pegar só o do título?

Comment: @OliverDamon Coloquei no final da resposta. Valeu!

Comment: Vlw. Ajudou muito, mano.